# Fetch sender email address in Gmail message list API

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api

I'm using Gmail API to fetch email address (of the sender) for last 10 emails. 
URL: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list

But `Users.messages: list` API returns message resource (which includes only email ID).
And for fetching sender email address, I have to make one `Users.messages: get` API call for each message resources, that's increases load time.

How can I fetch email address of sender along with email ID in the response of `Users.messages: list` API? 
 
OR Somehow I can fetch last 10 sender email address in one API call?

**My current code Example:**

```
$params = [
    'labelIds' => 'INBOX',
    'maxResults' => 10
];
$emails = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', $params);
foreach ($emails->getMessages() as $email) {
    $email_data = $service->users_messages->get('me', $email->id, ['format' => 'full']);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I fetch email address of sender along with email ID in the response of Users.messages: list API?

#### Answer:

*You can't, `Users.messages: get` needs to be used to retrieve this information.*

#### More Information:

As per the [`Users.messages: list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) documentation about the properties of the response resource:

> `messages[]`: **List of messages.** Note that each message resource contains only an id and a threadId. Additional message details can be fetched using the [`messages: get`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get) method.

The [`Users.message` resource](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource) page gives more information about the full response which is able to be retrieved from `messages: get`:

```json
{
  "id": string,
  "threadId": string,
  "labelIds": [
    string
  ],
  "snippet": string,
  "historyId": unsigned long,
  "internalDate": long,
  "payload": {
    "partId": string,
    "mimeType": string,
    "filename": string,
    "headers": [
      {
        "name": string,
        "value": string
      }
    ],
    "body": users.messages.attachments Resource,
    "parts": [
      (MessagePart)
    ]
  },
  "sizeEstimate": integer,
  "raw": bytes
}
```

#### What you need to do:

In order to get the message ID and sender email address, you need to make a `Users.messages: list` call to get the email IDs, then make a `Users.messages: get` request on each message ID to get the sender email. **As there is no `Users.messages: batchGet` method, there is unfortunately no way around this.**

#### References:

- [`Users.messages: list` | Gmail API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list)
- [`Users.messages: get` | Gmail API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get)
- [`Users.messages` | Gmail API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages#resource)

Comment: Thanks Rafa, I have already done that way. 
Google should provide at least sender and receiver along with list API.